# E.F Context - Stored procedure and Query

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I am getting an entity :

```
Account account;

account = context.Accounts.where(_ => _accountId = 1).FirstOrDefault();
```

Then I am running a stored procedure that is changing data on my Accounts table :

```
string query = string.Format("{0} {1}",
                          "SpUpdateAccount",
                          "@AccountId";

var results = context.Database.SqlQuery<int>(query,
                                             paramAccountId);
```

After that I want to get my account entity with the new changes :

```
account = context.Accounts.where(_ => _accountId = 1).FirstOrDefault();
```

So my account does not get the updates done by the Stored Procedure, however when I run a query against my database the record is updated. So somehow my issue is on the E.F, since it's not getting the database changes.

Thanks

Comment: what version of Entity Framework?

Comment: @DavidColwell I am using EF 6 Thanks

Comment: Are the two calls to `context.Accounts.Where(...)` in the same `using` statement?

Comment: No, actually the issue was what @jnovo below answered. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the same context, it will not realize that the entities have changed and it will return you the same local object stored in memory instead of querying the database again. You may either create a fresh new context or detach your previous object before re-querying [using `Detach`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738697.aspx):

```
context.Detach(account);
account = context.Accounts.where(_ => _accountId = 1).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: I will try and let you know @jnovo